# Joining invoices and shipping records based on partial info

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope this is just a case of me not knowing the terminology to search for, but I haven't found any hint of how to solve this yet.

I am trying to join two tables (invoices and shipping records) where some of the info is missing. In particular the account code and order number which I would usually use to join on.

Given that each order is fairly unique in the exact mix of products and quantities I am hoping it is possible to join the tables by comparing the composition of the orders.

For example given the data below it ought to be possible to identify that the shipping record for `order_ref` A1 is related to `invoice_num` 500 as it contains the same products in exactly the same quantities.

```
  shipping_id | order_ref | product | quantity 
 -------------|-----------|---------|---------- 
          100 | A1        | Apple   |        1 
          101 | A1        | Banana  |        1 
          102 | A1        | Carrot  |        2 


  invoice_num | line_num | product | quantity 
 -------------|----------|---------|---------- 
          500 |        1 | Apple   |        1 
          500 |        2 | Banana  |        1 
          500 |        3 | Carrot  |        2 
          501 |        1 | Apple   |       10 
          501 |        2 | Banana  |        1 
          501 |        3 | Carrot  |        2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a key for each group, and join with this key.

In your sample, `Apple_1_Banana_1_Carrot_2_` key will create for order_ref = "A1" of shipping and invoice_num = "500" of invoice.

```
DECLARE @shipping TABLE  (shipping_id INT, order_ref VARCHAR(10), product VARCHAR(10), quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @shipping VALUES
(100 , 'A1', 'Apple', 1), 
(101 , 'A1', 'Banana', 1), 
(102 , 'A1', 'Carrot', 2) 

DECLARE @invoice TABLE  (invoice_num INT, line_num INT, product VARCHAR(10), quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @invoice VALUES
(500, 1 ,'Apple',  1 ),
(500, 2 ,'Banana',  1 ),
(500, 3 ,'Carrot',  2 ),
(501, 1 ,'Apple', 10 ),
(501, 2 ,'Banana',  1 ),
(501, 3 ,'Carrot',  2 )

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM @shipping s
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT product + '_' + CAST(quantity AS varchar(10)) + '_'  
            FROM @shipping s2 WHERE s.order_ref = s2.order_ref 
            ORDER BY product , quantity FOR XML PATH('')) X(group_key)
) A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM @invoice i
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT product + '_' + CAST(quantity AS varchar(10)) + '_'  
            FROM @invoice i2 WHERE i.invoice_num = i2.invoice_num 
            ORDER BY product , quantity FOR XML PATH('')) X(group_key) 
)B ON A.group_key = B.group_key 
    AND A.product = B.product
    AND A.quantity = B.quantity
```

Result:

```
shipping_id order_ref  product    quantity    line_num             invoice_num line_num    product    quantity   
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
100         A1         Apple      1           1                    500         1           Apple      1          
101         A1         Banana     1           2                    500         2           Banana     1          
102         A1         Carrot     2           3                    500         3           Carrot     2
```

Answer (score 0):

join on product and quantity instead:

```
select table_a.*, table_b.* 
from table_a
join table_b on table_a.product = table_b.product
and  table_a.quantity = table_b.quantity
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I need to join on the complete make up of the order so this will give me too many false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a proper SQL way to join like this but you could do something like the following:

```
SELECT order_ref, STRING_AGG(product + quantity, '_') as product_list
FROM
(SELECT * FROM shipping_records ORDER BY product) AS inner_shipping_records
GROUP BY
order_ref
```

and then

```
SELECT invoice_num, STRING_AGG(product + quantity, '_') as product_list
FROM
(SELECT * FROM invoices ORDER BY product) AS inner_invoices
GROUP BY
invoice_num
```

and then do your join on the product_list fields:

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT order_ref, STRING_AGG(.... ) as a_products JOIN
( SELECT invoice_num, STRING_AGG(.... ) as a_shipping_records
ON a_products.product_list = a_shipping_records.product_list
```

I haven't tested this on SQL Server but it should work.  I don't think it would be fast but you could work out some kind of functional index or views that could speed this up.

Comment: It seem's Serkan's answer does much the same thing so I appreciate the logic here. and I hear what you say about speed, but this is only to mop up the remaining 5% of orders which have poor data quality so speed is not essential.

Comment: No problem.  My solution doesn't give you quite the same output though.  I was aiming for just a list of order_ref vs invoice_num not all the products related to that order.  Glad you got your solution.